# Any idea on performing localization & mapping using a Velodyne VLP-16 LIDAR?

Tags: ros-kinetic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. I want to do the SLAM for a humanoid robot with Stanley Innovations's RMP-220 V3 Base Platform and Velodyne VLP-16 LIDAR. Do I have to use an IMU? to perform this?

I am using ROS Kinetic. I have found out that Velodyne drivers support have released only till ROS Indigo. Using Kinetic will be a problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243267/any-idea-on-performing-localization-&-mapping-using-a-velodyne-vlp-16-lidar?/) by [Aswin Sarang](https://answers.ros.org/users/27924/aswin-sarang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It works on Jade and Kinetic, if built from source. Binary packages are still pending.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0